# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in RelationshipsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I wanted to create twitter like followers and following thing.
in my view i have

```
<% if current_user.following?(@otheruser) %>
   <%= render 'unfollow' %>
<% else %>
   <%= render 'follow' %>
<% end %>
```

in `_follow.html.erb`

```
 <%= form_for (@otheruser), url: createfollower_path(@otheruser) ,:class=>"form-horizontal",method: :post do |f|  %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @otheruser.id %>
      <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 <% end %>
```

in controller create action

```
def create
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    current_user.follow(user)
    redirect_to followuser_url
end
```

in `user.rb`

```
has_many :followers, class_name: "Relationship" #-> users following you
has_many :following, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: :follower_id, foreign_key: :user_id   

  def follow(other_user)
    relationships.create(user_id: other_user.id)
  end
```

in `relationship.rb`

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
    validates :user, :follower, presence: true
    validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :follower_id }
end
```

now when I am trying to submit the follow button it is showing error as 
"Couldn't find User with 'id'=" and parameters are

```
{"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"681q5ft03+WRdqgHagh/gI1mV3uohwaEj1sF8zdTycUAN5yTiVMT/wGCV4tLPRVRRFRA+6mYSS1bXk2ormA/zw==",
 "user"=>{"user_id"=>"7"},
 "commit"=>"Follow",
 "format"=>"7"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite your controller's `create action`.

```
def create
    user = User.find(params[:user][:user_id])
    current_user.follow(user)
    redirect_to followuser_url
 end
```

Should worked !!!